# How can I make my Javascript .map functions more efficient?

Tags: javascript, opensearch

I'm currently returning a large set of data from AWS OpenSearch into an array called `eventList`. Each event within the array has the following structure:

```
{
  _source: {
    "key": value
    "key": value
    "key": value
  }
}
```

I therefore want to destructure this so that `_source` becomes the event data and then map over eventList. Currently, I've got two .map instances, and I'm aware this isn't that efficient, so I'd like to know how to combine these.

```
let eventList = [
  {
    _source: {
      tags: "xxx,yyy,zzz"
      ...
    }
  }
];

eventList = eventList.map((event) => event._source);
eventList = eventList.map((event) => {
  const { tags } = event;

  return {
    ...event,
    tags: tags?.split(",") ?? [],
  };
});
```

Comment: At the very least you can cut the number of iterations in half by doing all the transformations inside a single function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say in the question, you can combine those two `map` calls:

```
eventList = eventList.map(({_source}) => (
    ..._source,
    tags: _source.tags?.split(",") ?? [],
));
```

I've used destructuring in the parameter list, but you don't *have* to do that if you don't want:

```
eventList = eventList.map((event) => (
    ...event._source,
    tags: event._source.tags?.split(",") ?? [],
));
```

There are a hundred different ways to write that, but you get the idea.

Actually, we could take the destructuring further:

```
eventList = eventList.map(({_source: {tags, ...rest}}) => (
    ...rest,
    tags: tags?.split(",") ?? [],
));
```

But all of these variations should be roughly the same in terms of performance; the big win is having just one `map`.